# android edit text got hidden below keyboard on pressing any key

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have edit text on bottom of activity. when i enter value in edit text. keyboard appears from bottom and edit text got hidden below the keyboard.
Please, help me sorting it out.
 I have used this in manifest file: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"`

and also put this line of code in `oncreate()` function :

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But, still problem is there :( please help me.

Comment: try with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you would only try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize".can you check whether your problem is solved or not and if you are tired of doing all the stuffs always prefer to use ScrollView as the parent of your layout which you are specifically using for adding your views for example Buttons,TextViews and so on..

I prefer this as the best way.When you try to do it the first time you will face some difficulties but when you get used to it then you will achieve your problem's solution.Try it

Comment: Ya, i know but, i have already used a scrollView, and in eclipse xml, two scroll views at the same time dont work properly and smothly.. thats the problem. . .